# Indexing on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a kind of request for Postgres database. I have below query running and creating a lot of cost:

select MESSAGEID, INDEX_NAME, OPERATION,ADDED from B2BBP_INDEX_SYNC where INDEX_NAME = $1 order by added asc

For now I have the index for INDEX_NAME column but since there is order by in the end, my index didn't get any hits from create index. Is there a way to manage this kind of cases in Postgres?

Here is the execution plan:

```
"Gather Merge  (cost=10575980.59..14212080.65 rows=31164396 width=113)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=10574980.57..10613936.06 rows=15582198 width=113)"
"        Sort Key: added"
"        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on b2bbp_index_sync  (cost=0.00..5837409.47 rows=15582198 width=113)"
"              Filter: ((index_name)::text = 'B3P_SEARCH_INDEX_DIRECTORY'::text)"
```

- also adding the analyse:

```html
"Gather Merge  (cost=10575982.01..14212082.77 rows=31164402 width=113) (actual time=104236.195..115849.741 rows=37399386 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  Workers Launched: 2"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=10574981.98..10613937.48 rows=15582201 width=113) (actual time=102579.407..105452.466 rows=12466462 loops=3)"
"        Sort Key: added"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1624864kB"
"        Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1551568kB"
"        Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1581024kB"
"        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on b2bbp_index_sync  (cost=0.00..5837410.51 rows=15582201 width=113) (actual time=0.468..73882.771 rows=12466462 loops=3)"
"              Filter: ((index_name)::text = 'B3P_SEARCH_INDEX_DIRECTORY'::text)"
"Planning Time: 0.079 ms"
"Execution Time: 117928.196 ms"
```

Comment: can you share your execution plan too ?

Comment: "Seq Scan on b2bbp_index_sync  (cost=0.00..6110066.54 rows=37397083 width=113)"
"  Filter: ((index_name)::text = 'B3P_SEARCH_INDEX_DIRECTORY'::text)" 

seems it not using any indexes...

Comment: it would be better to put that execution plan into question with a nice formatting, it will help

Comment: Just updated the initial question. thanks for the heads up.

Comment: "*Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1624864kB"*. Disk sort in taking 99% of the time, Try adding 1G or 2G more memory (work_mem). Disk sort is the about the  slowest thing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If the value specified in $1 is used by a lot of rows (more than 5% of the DB), Postgres will often decide to go for a SeqScan (reading through the whole table) rather than fetching too many rows from the index (this kinda make sense, because the index would basically tell PG to read the whole table anyway).

Can you add an EXPLAIN ANALYZE statement to your query too? It could help us debug further.